# Efficient way to sort a formatted array (Chris Pine book, ch 7)

Tags: ruby, formatting

I'm on chapter 7 of Chris Pine's book, trying to work on the last exercise in that chapter. This code works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this...

```
toc_array = ['Table of Contents',  'Chapter 1:  Numbers', 'page 1', 'Chapter 2:  Letters',  'page 72', 'Chapter 3:  Variables', 'page 118']
linewidth = 30
puts toc_array[0].center(linewidth*2)
puts (toc_array[1].ljust(linewidth)) + (toc_array[1].rjust(linewidth))
puts (toc_array[2].ljust(linewidth)) + (toc_array[3].rjust(linewidth))
puts (toc_array[4].ljust(linewidth)) + (toc_array[5].rjust(linewidth))
```

Is there more efficient way to print the formatted array?

Comment: What does this have to do with sorting (as indicated in the title)?

Comment: Elements of the array have to be sorted [0-5] and then formatted in a certain way.

Comment: They _are_ sorted, as far as I can tell. Heading, followed by chapters and page numbers in their proper order. All that's left is formatting

Comment: Please check that you got your array indexes right. The output looks suspiciously wrong.

Comment: There is no output in my message. If you do run it, it will print fine. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Er, no, the code doesn't work fine. I get:

```
                     Table of Contents                      
Chapter 1:  Numbers                      Chapter 1:  Numbers
page 1                                   Chapter 2:  Letters
page 72                                Chapter 3:  Variables
```

Chapters and page numbers are reversed (compared to a regular table of contents anyway), and chapter 1's page number isn't shown.

Anyway, I assume you can figure out what array indices should be fixed.

Point #2: `linewidth` is a bad name. It's exactly *half* of the desired linewidth.

Point #3: DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself. Go read the documentation for [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html) and the [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html) module that's included in `Array`: You practically *never* have to manually copy lines and change indexes

Given these inputs

```
toc_array = ['Table of Contents',  'Chapter 1:  Numbers', 'page 1', 'Chapter 2:  Letters',  'page 72', 'Chapter 3:  Variables', 'page 118']
line_width = 60
half_line_width = line_width / 2
```

it's much easier to do this

```
puts toc_array.shift.center(line_width)
toc_array.each_slice(2) do |chapter, page|
  puts chapter.ljust(half_line_width) + page.rjust(half_line_width)
end
```

which gives you

```
                     Table of Contents                      
Chapter 1:  Numbers                                   page 1
Chapter 2:  Letters                                  page 72
Chapter 3:  Variables                               page 118
```

Comment: Ooo... there are many things there that I don't know yet. What are those (2) arguments in the array toc_array.each_slice(2)?

Comment: @user39963 See the the docs for `each_slice` (already linked in my answer). If you mean the two arguments for the block: [Destructuring](http://tony.pitluga.com/2011/08/08/destructuring-with-ruby.html). `each_slice(2)` loops over an array, 2 elements at a time, passing those elements to the block as a array. But because ruby let's you use destructuring, the two elements are assigned to `chapter` and `title` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is very brittle and hard-coded. Code is supposed to be as generic and flexible as possible so you could re-use it. A new chapter, a different layout, anything would require you to change the whole code.

Code is about doing work *for you*. Think generically - can this code be used for a different book? (I don't mean by you copying it, pasting it and changing it...)

You need to abstract it - what do you have here?

You have a `title`, which is different than a `chapter`. A `chapter` has a `page number`. There are some chapters in a book. The TOC needs to be laid out using some logic...

`title` and `chapter` are *objects* is your system, the layout logic is a *method*.

For example - I pass to a method called `format_toc` a title, and a list of chapters, which (for simplicity) contain their name and their page number in an array. The method than lays out the TOC page according to the format in your code. Note that the *data* does not contain the words `'Chapter'` or `'page'` - they are part of the layout, not the data:

```
def format_toc(title, chapters)
  line_width = 30
  toc = chapters.each_with_index.map do |chapter, i|
    "Chapter #{i}: #{chapter[0]}".ljust(line_width) + "page #{chapter[1]}".rjust(line_width)
  end.join("\n")
  "#{title.center(line_width*2)}\n#{toc}"
end
puts format_toc 'Table of Contents', [['Numbers', 1], ['Letters',  72], ['Variables', 118]]
#=>                     Table of Contents                      
#=>Chapter 1:  Numbers                                   page 1
#=>Chapter 2:  Letters                                  page 72
#=>Chapter 3:  Variables                               page 118
```

---

**But wait - you are still using hard-coded indexes!**
True, `[0]` and `[1]` are still there, which looks a little "hard-coded", but these indexes refer to the data *structure*, not the data itself. A more elaborate design would likely use a hash to hold chapter data (`{name: 'Numbers', page: 1}`), or even a class having two properties, but for the example above it shows the concept of *encapsulation* - as long as two modules know the *language* (=API), they can independently change things in their domain (wither adding chapters to the book, or change the layout), without affecting other parts of the code.

I also took the liberty of changing the structure of the input, as @Flambino remarked, but only because I assumed the choice of the structure of the input was not an outside constraint, but a design choice (it didn't make much sense otherwise).

Comment: Sorry, but -1 for the code: You still have a hard coded index, and you're changing the input array's "format" to suit your code

Comment: Thank you, Uri. I liked the main concepts you mentioned in your answer. It never occurred to me to make layout a method.

Comment: @Flambino - see my addition to the answer

Comment: Read it, and must admit I was too quick on the trigger earlier - I apologize, and I've cancelled my downvote. For whatever reason, I read `chapter[i]` in one place, and `chapter[1]` in another, and assumed it was leftover code - that's what I meant by "hard coded indexes", but I simply misread it. As for changing the input data's structure, I assumed the opposite of you: that it was an outside constraint. I don't know. But I figured that was "the challenge" so to speak; otherwise the simplest solution is to structure the input to match the intended output and skip the code :)